# Understanding 切れやすくしてあります

Tags: grammar, meaning

「これ、ガムテープです。それも非常に粘着力のある。**それに鋏を入れ、切れやすくしてあります**。」

The only thing I can understand is "切れやすい" which means "easy to cut", but what is くしてあります doing here? Could it mean something like "I made it (or it has been made) easy to cut with scissors"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「～～くしてある」

means:

> "(it has been) made/produced so that ~~"

So, this particular type of packing tape **comes precut so it is naturally easy to cut**.

To mention the grammar used, 「切れやす**く**」 is the 連用形{れんようけい}  ("continuative form") of 「切れやす**い**」.

Comment: Isn’t this the adverbial form?

Comment: @mamster Yeah, the 連用形「～く」 functions adverbially... but we generally call the forms 「～く」「～かっ」「～う」(eg「やすく」「やすかっ」「やすう」) as 連用形(continuative forms)... It is more common among Japanese learners to call 連用形 like「白く」「静かに」「走り」 as "adverbial form"?

Comment: I don't know how typical my education is, but for adjectives specifically, I remember learning 「白く」and「静かに」as the adverbial form, and we didn't learn the use of the continuative form until much later, so I think of them as different even when they're written the same way.